# what does ternary operator Uniswap createPair function does?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, uniswap, defi

```
function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair) {
        require(tokenA != tokenB, 'UniswapV2: IDENTICAL_ADDRESSES');
        (address token0, address token1) = tokenA < tokenB ? (tokenA, tokenB) : (tokenB, tokenA);
        require(token0 != address(0), 'UniswapV2: ZERO_ADDRESS');
        require(getPair[token0][token1] == address(0), 'UniswapV2: PAIR_EXISTS'); // single check is sufficient
        bytes memory bytecode = type(UniswapV2Pair).creationCode;
        bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1));
        assembly {
            pair := create2(0, add(bytecode, 32), mload(bytecode), salt)
        }
        IUniswapV2Pair(pair).initialize(token0, token1);
        getPair[token0][token1] = pair;
        getPair[token1][token0] = pair; // populate mapping in the reverse direction
        allPairs.push(pair);
        emit PairCreated(token0, token1, pair, allPairs.length);
    }
```

I am unable to understand what does  this line of code do. It is comparing tokenA with tokenB of address type. Any more explanation will be very helpful.
`(address token0, address token1) = tokenA < tokenB ? (tokenA, tokenB) : (tokenB, tokenA);`

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for what the ternary operator does, it is equivalent to an if /else statement in a more compact (and less obvious) form.

```
condition ? do_that_if_condition_is_true : do_that_if_condition_is_false;
```

---

In your specific code segment it is used to order addresses in a specific way before creating a token pair. The ordering ensures that the first token address is a lower number than the second token address (Your address is simply an hex representation of what is essentially an integer, which you can compare).

Ex: with tokenA = address(100) and tokenB = address(50)

- token0 = tokenB
- token1 = tokenA

Where : pair always equals (token1, token2).

This is essentially what this line does:

```
(address token0, address token1) = tokenA < tokenB ? (tokenA, tokenB) : (tokenB, tokenA);
```

Given that :

1. An address is unique
2. Token addresses cannot be equal ( `require(tokenA != tokenB, 'UniswapV2: IDENTICAL_ADDRESSES');`)

The ordering is guaranteed to provide a unique identifier for a given pair.

Finally a simple check is enough to validate if that pair already exists or not :

```
require(getPair[token0][token1] == address(0), 'UniswapV2: PAIR_EXISTS'); // single check is sufficient
```

If not, it can be created.

Answer (score 1):

Uniswap v2 ensures that there is only one pool per a pair of tokens. That is to say, if there already is a pool with tokens (A, B) it is not possible to create a new pool with the same tokens in different order: (B, A).

The way Uniswap ensures this is by always ordering the tokens based on their contract addresses. This line makes sure that whatever the addresses of `tokenA` and `tokenB` are, the address of `token0` is always lexicographically smaller than the address of `token1`:

```
(address token0, address token1) = tokenA < tokenB ? (tokenA, tokenB) : (tokenB, tokenA);
```

It could be rewritten like this:

```
address token0;
address token1;
if (tokenA < tokenB) {
  token0 = tokenA;
  token1 = tokenB;
} else {
  token0 = tokenB;
  token1 = tokenA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The analogy given in the above answers that it will generate a unique identifier, and we can compare it with the pair and see whether or not it already exists or not is not why we are exactly doing it.

- First of all, that's because you can see later in the code that we are reverse-populating the mapping, so at the end of the day, it does not matter as it will give you the same pool address.

  ```
   getPair[token0][token1] = pair;
   getPair[token1][token0] = pair; // populate mapping in the reverse direction
  ```
- We are doing it cause we are using create2, which helps us generate predetermined contract addresses. In order to generate the predetermined address. You have to have the same order of the variables. For instance, you can see the line

  ```
  bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1));
  ```

I've attached the screenshot from the remix and you can see that just by changing the `order` the salt changes thus it will affect the contract address.

[image]

[image]

in `UniswapV2Library` we have these two functions where you can see we are sorting the addresses via `sortTokens` function and using it in `pairFor` function which generates the contract address, rather than making an external call.

This means we have to make sure that we always generate the same address when the input and order are the same.

```
// returns sorted token addresses, used to handle return values from pairs sorted in this order
function sortTokens(address tokenA, address tokenB) internal pure returns (address token0, address token1) {
    require(tokenA != tokenB, 'UniswapV2Library: IDENTICAL_ADDRESSES');
    (token0, token1) = tokenA < tokenB ? (tokenA, tokenB) : (tokenB, tokenA);
    require(token0 != address(0), 'UniswapV2Library: ZERO_ADDRESS');
}

// calculates the CREATE2 address for a pair without making any external calls
function pairFor(address factory, address tokenA, address tokenB) internal pure returns (address pair) {
    (address token0, address token1) = sortTokens(tokenA, tokenB);
    pair = address(uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
            hex'ff',
            factory,
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1)),
            hex'e18a34eb0e04b04f7a0ac29a6e80748dca96319b42c54d679cb821dca90c6303' // init code hash
        ))));
}
```